# Blank Black screen appear after upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32-bit to 18.04 LTS 32-bit bionic beaver via software updater during reboot

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, update-manager, 32-bit

I was upgrading my laptop running ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32 bit version to a ubuntu 18.04 LTS 32 bit version bionic beaver via the software updater builtin the OS. After successful installation of the operating system, while rebooting the system I encountered a blank black screen after the boot image of the ubuntu.

Please someone let me know will the 18.04 LTS 32 bit version work on a PC having 1 GB RAM? (IF YES then how to make it work) or shall I downgrade back to ubuntu 16.04 ?

I also lost the GRUB menu which is displayed before booting into the Operating System.

Specifications of my laptop are:

-Processor: Intel Atom dual core 1Ghz.

-RAM: 1 GB

-Hard Disk: 160 GB

-Model name: Acer aspire one netbook.

PS:

1. I am well aware of the fact the ubuntu 18.04 LTS iso file is not available as a 32 bit version on their website.
2. I tried upgrading my system using mini.iso file (available here http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/18.04/) of the ubuntu 18.04 LTS 32 bit version, still I'm facing the same issue of running into the blank black screen.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: 16.04 is supported until 2021. Even today it's hard to wrap one's head around the idea of using such outdated hardware, let alone keep using it past 2021! So, yes, keep 16.04 until you make you PC a donation to a museum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Ubuntu Mate or Lubuntu. Works fine on 1GB RAM